# Rationals: dense ordering question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-numbers

I'm reading about construction of $\mathbb{Q}$ on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number#Formal_construction) and dense ordering on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_order).

In the former:

$(\frac a b < \frac c d) \implies (\frac a b < \frac {a + c} {b + d} < \frac c d)$

Is a theorem that establishes this? How adding numerators and denominators yields a fraction in between.

Comment: try cross-multiplying

Comment: You need to take care with signs (always multiply by a positive number to maintain the inequality), but clearing fractions in each of the three inequalities in turn gives the result. This is a "theorem" once it has been proved.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just by using arithmetic. For example, $a(b+d) < b(a+c)$ because $ab+ad < ab+bc$ because $ad<bc$.